# How to correctly call a controller function with in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, function, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I am using a directive in my html page under the impression of a controller. I need to call a controller function from that directive but I am  unable to correctly do that. Every time there are some errors. Can Any body help me ? Please :(
Below is the code.

```js
app.directive('myGoogleAutocomplete', function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            googleModel: '=',
            onSelect: '&?', // optional callback on selected successfully: 'onPostedBid(googleModel)'
        },
        template: '<input class="form-control" type="text" style="z-index: 100000;" autocomplete="on">',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, model) {
            var googleOptions = {
                types: ['address'] // change or empty it, if you want no restrictions
            };

            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], googleOptions);

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {


                /**
                 * Search gor the passed 'type' of info into the google place component
                 * @param {type} components
                 * @param {type} type
                 * @returns {type} 
                 */
                $scope.extract = function (components, type) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < components.length; i++)
                        for (var j = 0; j < components[i].types.length; j++)
                            if (components[i].types[j] == type) return components[i].short_name;
                    return '';
                };


                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                    if (!place.geometry)
                     {
                        // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
                        model.$setValidity('place', false);
                        //console.log("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
                        return;
                    }


                    console.log($scope.googleModel.longitude);

                    console.log($scope.googleModel.latitude);
      $scope.thisFunct(); //want to call controller func here

                    if (place.address_components) {
                        $scope.googleModel.address = [
                            $scope.extract(place.address_components, 'route'),
                            $scope.extract(place.address_components, 'street_number')
                        ].join(' ');

                    }

                    model.$setViewValue(element.val());
                    model.$setValidity('place', true);
                    if (attrs.onSelect) $scope.onSelect({ $item: $scope.googleModel });
                });
            });
        }
    }
});

//
app.controller("featureController", function($scope,$http,$rootScope,close,ModalService,NgMap) {
        $scope.thisFunct=function()
        {
            console.log("Reached Here finally! Success ");
        }
```

```html
  <my-google-autocomplete id="address"   name="address"
      ng-model="task.house_no" google-model="model.googleAddress"
      on-select="vm.onSelectGoogleAddress($item)" autocomplete="off"
      required>
  </my-google-autocomplete>
```

Comment: ans. is deleted rahi.shah

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The code `$scope.onSelect({ $item: $scope.googleModel })` correctly calls the function. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

In scope of directive, to call the function:

```
<div my-directive callback-fn="ctrlFn(arg1)"></div>


 app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: { someCtrlFn: '&callbackFn' },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.someCtrlFn({arg1: 22});
        },
    }
});


 function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.ctrlFn = function(test) {
        console.log(test);
    }
}
```